# GUI bug on hiding ribbon

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, ribbon

I've got a strange behavior with the Microsoft ribbon library (the library which is included in .Net Framework 4.5). If I hide the complete ribbon, the areas below the ribbon tab headers look really ugly. I've build a test application and was able to reproduce this behavior (screen below)

[image]

The code of this application is very simple:

```
<Window x:Class="RibbonLibraryTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="Yellow">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ribbon Background="White">
            <RibbonTab Header="Test1"></RibbonTab>
            <RibbonTab Header="Test2"></RibbonTab>
            <RibbonTab Header="Test3"></RibbonTab>
            <RibbonTab Header="Test4"></RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To hide the ribbon, I double click on one of the ribbon tabs like in MS Word. 
Seems to be a bug in the ribbon library. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Could you share a code or a link to a project? When you say hidden do you mean visibility=hidden or collapsed? or are you using another tactic?

Comment: I added the code now to my question. To hide the window I double click on one of the ribbon tabs.

Comment: We had a similar problem which was caused through global styles. Do you use any? If so does it work without them?

Comment: I use no global styles. This is a very simple test application which only consists of the code I posted in my question.

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by *look really ugly* in perhaps slightly more technical terms? I can see the picture, but the only *really ugly* thing that I can see is the yellow background.

Comment: Look at the left side of the ribbon, right from the application menu. The line below the ribbon items is not continous. It is interrupted below the ribbon tab headers.